# Unable to delete record: Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria

Tags: delete, record

I am trying to delete some records but I am stopped by the error message "**Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.**"

I have already disabled all filters all lookup-fields on the object but I still get the same error message. What do I have to do to be able to delete these records?

Comment: Are you getting the error on screen or in debug logs?

Comment: The error is shown on screen

Comment: If you see the issue on the screen itself which means the lookup field on the same object or lookup field on the related object which used this object may cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a look-up filter on another (related) object. Disabling the filter there solved the issue and made it possible to delete the records.